# Gatling can not find simulations under user-files dir

Tags: gatling

This has been working previously on deployments to a remote server but we are now seeing errors of:

```
There is no simulation script. Please check that your scripts are in user-files/simulations
```

Locally, this works absolutely fine and we do not see this error. We have made a tar of the entire gatling repo and also checked the permissions of the files which have the permissions both on server and locally of:

```
-rw-r--r--
```

Both server and local are using Java 8. I have read related question which suggest this is to do with heap space or Gatling not finding Java. Since Java is installed on the server what else could be causing this? All simulations are directly under: user-files/simulations/